# Can I bring my old aged parents to Germany permanently?

Tags: germany, citizenship, family, german-citizens

I have become a German citizen. Can I bring my old aged parents to Germany permanently?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the answer is no. There is no general right for parents to join their adult children in Germany, family reunion only applies to spouses, minor children and parents of a minor children with German citizenship. It is possible to get a visa in special hardship cases (*Vermeidung einer außergewöhnlichen Härte*), e.g. if you can prove your parents need special care (*Pflegebedürftigkeit*) and cannot get it in their current country of residence, but not simply because they are your parents and you would prefer to live together.

Comment: The correct terminology is: **außergewöhnlichen Härte** (*Pflegebedürftigkeit* is only one possibility of many), for family members not covered in § 28: [§36(2) AufenthG - Subsequent immigration of parents and other family members](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0830): *Other family members of a foreigner may be granted a temporary residence permit for the purpose of subsequent immigration to join the foreigner if necessary in order to avoid **exceptional hardship**. ...*

Comment: @MarkJohnson Indeed, I already quoted the proper terminology, no need to bold it, and ”e.g.” means ”exempli gratia”. It's a common way to introduce an example in English. Maybe you confused it with ”i.e.”?